# Images only displaying in Safari - HTML

Tags: html, image, browser, safari

I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS so with a bit of luck there is an easy fix to my problem.

I have a few images for my site, 1 as a background image and 2 which are just sitting in the body. In safari everything displays flawlessly however in Chrome, Firefox and Opera only 1 of the images in the body displays.

I've tried searching for answers, the only suggestion that I can find is to disable ad-block which resulted in no-change.

I've also tried disabling the stylesheet but the problem still persists.

```
<div class="photocontainer" id="homepage"><h4 id="phototext">A Guide to Quality Web Development</h4></div>

        <div class="Body">
        <h2>We're here to <Span>help.</Span></h2>


        <img id="plan" src="./images/plan.jpg" alt="plan">
        <img id="flowchart" src="./images/flowchart.jpg" alt="flowchart"/>
```

The above code contains the 3 images. The second of which is the only one that works.

I should mention that the photocontainer div has a background-image specified by the stylesheet.

Comment: `The above code contains the 3 images` Are you sure?  I may be blind, but I only count 2 `<img>` tags.  Is the third a CSS background or something?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
I suggest changing you `src` codes.

From `src="./images/plan.jpg"`
To `src="plan.jpg"`

Option 2:
Add `width` and `height` codes to your `<img>` tags.

Option 3:
Try removing the `id` from one of the `<img>` tags.

I hope one of these work. Try to mix them around. Like removing the `id` and adding the `width` and `height` too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

The images themselves had trouble opening. Opened them in photoshop and then saved for web. Not it works.